# Auto Increment Composite Primary Key

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, composite-primary-key

I have an Access database that I am trying to create. I want to use two columns from the table to create the primary key.

```
Projectbl (ProjectID, ProjectRegion, other columns)
```

I want the `ProjectID` to autoincrement. That's fine. So far whenever I add a new project, the `ProjecID` increments by itself.

I want to create a new column in that same table that will be the `ProjectRef` where the new number would be a composite of `ProjectID` and `ProjectRegion`.

So for example

```
ProjectID ProjectRegion OtherCol 
---------------------------------
1            500          ...
2            100          ...
3            200          ...
4            500          ...
5            500          ...
6            100          ...
```

I want the table to actually look like that

```
ProjectRef ProjectID ProjectRegion OtherCol 
--------------------------------------------
5001        1            500          ...
1002        2            100          ...
2003        3            200          ...
5004        4            500          ...
5005        5            500          ...
1006        6            100          ...
```

So I am trying to add a new project: the `projectID` will autoincrement to 7, but the `ProjectRef` will be `'ProjectReg'7` whatever the `ProjectReg` is.

I know I can create a composite key with

```
CREATE TABLE 'Projectbl'
(
     ProjectID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ProjectRegion INT(10) NOT NULL,
     other columns VARCHAR(100),

     CONSTRAINT ProjectRef 
         PRIMARY KEY ('ProjectRegion', 'ProjectID')
)
```

How can I actually display `ProjectRef` in the table?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Access and every time I try to run the query create table, it say syntax error in the Auto_Increment. But before the auto_increment, I run it. I want to display the ProjectRef and have ProjectID autoincrement

Comment: What is the means by which new records come into the table? Most likely, you'll want a VBA function for this. It won't be terribly complicated, but it will allow you a lot of flexibility in how you perform this task.

Comment: Also, the syntax that you are using in the CREATE TABLE is SQL Server syntax, which often does not carry over to Access (Jet) SQL. That's probably why you're getting the syntax error.

Comment: @PatJones New record are added to this table from Excel import. Excel import has the Project Region and Other Columns but ProjectID when a new record is added, auto increment. I wanted to add a new Column called ProjectRef that identify the record with ProjectID and ProjectRegion

Comment: I see. Well, what you're trying to do is essentially a calculated column that depends on other columns. It's redundant. When you design the table, Access gives you the capability to define a compound key. You should do so with the two original columns and leave it like that.

Comment: @PatJones I understand what you mean. Design the table with the compound key and leave it like that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `ProjectRef` column at all. This violates basic rules of database normalization. If you want your front end to display the `ProjectRef` then just calculate it from the columns that you have.

Comment: Thank you :) . This make sense. I will create a compound primary key, not have the ProjectRef column and then on the front end, calculate it to show for the other users.

Comment: You don't need and don't want a composite primary key. As your ProjectID is an autonumber, each and every combination of ProjectRegion and ProjectID will be unique.